# Expected value found [object, Object] Query Params

Tags: javascript, graphql

I don't get it, I sent in the right input type here:

**Caller from JS code:**

```
export interface FilterInput {
    limit?: number;
}

const filter: FilterInput = { limit: 1 };
const query = {
    query: `query { 
        companies(filter: ${filter}) {
            list {
                name
            }
        }
    }`,
};
const response = await sendQuery(query);
```

**GraphQL Schema:**

```
companies(filter: FilterInput): Companies

input FilterInput {
  limit: Int
}
```

**Error:** `Expected value of type "FilterInput", found [object, Object].`

When I try this out in **graphiql** in the browser, it works fine:

```
query {
    companies(filter: { limit: 6 }) {
        list {
            name
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a js object in a template string directly resolves to `[object Object]` i.e. `${filter}` resolves to precisely `[object Object]` hence the error.

To solve it you can use `JSON.stringify(filter)`. Here is the string in the same format as before but with the fix:

```
`query { 
    companies(filter: ${JSON.stringify(filter)}) {
        list {
            name
        }
    }
}`
```

Comment: close, but I get an error that the limit is a string, not a property:  "Syntax Error: Expected Name, found String \"limit\"." for query { 
 companies(filter: {"limit":1}) {
  list {
   name
  }
 }
}

Comment: had to remove the double quotes with .replace(/"/g, '')

Comment: @PositiveGuy ah, I didn't expect GraphQL to care about quotes in the same way js doesn't. I guess the replace trick only works when you have non-strings in the object.